# Cut() function in r behaving differently for similar data

Tags: r

I am using the cut() function (base r) on two similar sets of data. On one set, I get the excepted output with cuts like (0.0253,0.0263] and on the other I get the range output mentioned in the help documentation (like Range_75). I am unable to identify what is different about my data that is causing this difference and would like some help in figuring out what the differences is.

If I could reproduce the example, I would share code to recreate it. So instead, here is information on my data & code:

The same line of code is used in a for loop, so both sets of data are being treated the same (temp_c is a data.frame, shown below):

```
temp_d<-as.numeric(temp_c[,1])
temp_c$grouping<-with(temp_c,cut(temp_d,breaks=quantile_c_temp,include.lowest=TRUE))
```

Here is what my temp_c data looks like:
head() for the data with the expected output (which I will call data_expected): data is in a data.frame and both columns are numeric

```
         var retention
1 0.00000000         1
2 0.02564103         0
3 0.00000000         0
4 0.00000000         1
5 0.00000000         0
6 0.21518987         1
```

head() for the data with the unexpected output (which I will call data_unexpected)

```
         var retention
1 0.31578947         1
2 0.28205128         0
3 0.25000000         0
4 0.00000000         1
5 0.04166667         0
6 0.15189873         1
```

Here are the breaks used in the cut function for data_expected (aka quantile_c_temp):

```
 [1] 0.000000000 0.008547009 0.010526316 0.012195122
 [5] 0.013698630 0.015384615 0.016949153 0.018181818
 [9] 0.019607843 0.020408163 0.021739130 0.022988506
[13] 0.024390244 0.025316456 0.026315789 0.027777778
[17] 0.029411765 0.030303030 0.032258065 0.033333333
[21] 0.034482759 0.035714286 0.037500000 0.039215686
[25] 0.040816327 0.041666667 0.043478261 0.045454545
[29] 0.047058824 0.048780488 0.050000000 0.052631579
[33] 0.054054054 0.055555556 0.058823529 0.060606061
[37] 0.062500000 0.065573770 0.068181818 0.071428571
[41] 0.073688109 0.076923077 0.078625892 0.082226461
[45] 0.084905660 0.089108911 0.091801020 0.095890411
[49] 0.100000000 0.103896104 0.108020556 0.111111111
[53] 0.117647059 0.122448980 0.127659574 0.134134819
[57] 0.142857143 0.148378041 0.156960784 0.166666667
[61] 0.185028180 0.200000000 0.238475317 0.500000000
```

Here are the breaks used in the cut function for data_unexpected (aka quantile_c_temp):

```
 [1] 0.00000000 0.01936819 0.03333333 0.04347826
 [5] 0.05071780 0.05802157 0.06422018 0.06896552
 [9] 0.07374374 0.07692308 0.08180891 0.08571429
[13] 0.09090909 0.09382131 0.09756098 0.10000000
[17] 0.10526316 0.10810811 0.11111111 0.11538462
[21] 0.11764706 0.12244898 0.12500000 0.12820513
[25] 0.13157895 0.13422000 0.13793103 0.14167717
[29] 0.14285714 0.14583333 0.14934809 0.15254237
[33] 0.15501802 0.15789474 0.16000000 0.16363636
[37] 0.16666667 0.16850635 0.17241379 0.17543860
[41] 0.17777778 0.18181818 0.18333333 0.18750000
[45] 0.18965517 0.19230769 0.19565217 0.20000000
[49] 0.20560880 0.20833333 0.21188012 0.21428571
[53] 0.21875000 0.22222222 0.22448980 0.22825348
[57] 0.23076923 0.23529412 0.23809524 0.24137931
[61] 0.24590164 0.25000000 0.25396115 0.25862069
[65] 0.26315789 0.26732673 0.27272727 0.27536232
[69] 0.28000000 0.28571429 0.28813559 0.29411765
[73] 0.30000000 0.30434783 0.31050037 0.31578947
[77] 0.32485811 0.33333333 0.33333333 0.34545455
[81] 0.35646771 0.36363636 0.37500000 0.38461538
[85] 0.39393939 0.40740741 0.42857143 0.44444444
[89] 0.46341463 0.49573770 0.51424242 0.57142857
[93] 0.66666667 1.00000000
```

As far as I can tell, the cuts produced by my code and data should either both be of the (0.0253,0.0263] type or both be of the Range_75 type. Does anyone have any idea why the cut-types are different?

Edit:
I ran dput(head(dat, 10)) on both data sets and got the following:
data_expected:

```
structure(list(var = c(0, 0.0256410256410256, 0, 0, 0, 0.215189873417722, 
0.027027027027027, 0, 0.0476190476190476, 0), retention = c(1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("var", "retention"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

data_unexpected:

```
structure(list(var = c(0.315789473684211, 0.282051282051282, 
0.25, 0, 0.0416666666666667, 0.151898734177215, 0.378378378378378, 
0, 0.0238095238095238, 0.208333333333333), retention = c(1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("var", "retention"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

My data is 8414 rows and when I subsetted down to 8411, the cuts were correct. There is something about row 8412. tail(data_unexpected)

```
            var retention
8409 0.05069124         1
8410 0.31034483         1
8411 0.26027397         0
8412 0.32116788         1
8413 0.10059172         1
8414 0.16666667         0
```

Comment: It sounds like the two datasets you are calling `cut` on are somehow stored in different formats. Therefore, it's essential that you share a reproducible example of the data so we can see how it's stored. If you have a data frame `dat`, then adding the output of `dput(head(dat, 10))` to the question would help us reproduce the first 10 rows. Having this for the two data sources would probably be sufficient to figure out what's going on here.

Comment: Thanks, I ran that and edited my original post to include the output here is the output for data_unexpected:

structure(list(var = c(0.315789473684211, 0.282051282051282, 
0.25, 0, 0.0416666666666667, 0.151898734177215, 0.378378378378378, 
0, 0.0238095238095238, 0.208333333333333), retention = c(1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("var", "retention"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: I still can't reproduce your error (I get normal-looking groupings for both data frames). Could you please edit your question so it has some data and code that we can run to exactly see it working with one data frame but not working with another? Something like `dat <- ...`, `quantile_c_temp <- ...`, `print(code that works on dat)`, `dat2 <- ...`, `quantile_c_temp <- ...`, `print(code that fails on dat2)`

Comment: My data is 8414 rows and when I subsetted down to 8411, the cuts were correct. There is something about row 8412. I can't find anything weird. Maybe my answer is just to delete row 8412. Tail(data_unexpected) is edited into the original post

Comment: Another user figured it out- it was a digit length issue and adding dig.lab=17 to my cut function fixed the issue. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Range_*` labels get invoked when `cut` can't create unique numeric labels properly with the specified number of digits:

> ‘dig.lab’ indicates the minimum number of digits [that] should be used in
>        formatting the numbers ‘b1’, ‘b2’, ....  A larger value (up to 12)
>        will be used if needed to distinguish between any pair of
>        endpoints: if this fails labels such as ‘"Range3"’ will be used.

Here's an example differentiating the two cases:

```
r1 <- 1+(1:4)*1e-15
cut(r1,r1)
## [1] <NA>    Range_1 Range_2 Range_3
## Levels: Range_1 Range_2 Range_3
r2 <- 1+(1:4)*1e-3
cut(r2,r2)
## [1] <NA>          (1.001,1.002] (1.002,1.003] (1.003,1.004]
## Levels: (1.001,1.002] (1.002,1.003] (1.003,1.004]
```

So one of your data sets has a set of cuts (`quantile_c_temp` that are so close together that their numeric representations are identical up to at least three digits. You can probably increase `dig.lab` from its default value of 3 to solve problem.

Comment: You are correct! Increasing dig.lab to 17 (nothing lower for my data) produced the correct breaks.

Thank you so much! I had read the help section, but couldn't make sense of what it meant. Your comment really cleared it up for me. Thank you!